# jquery form validation before ajax request?

Tags: ajax, jquery

this is a simple code to call the form validation function before submit it with ajax request

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#errors').hide();       
    var serializedData= $("#categoryForm").serialize();
    $("#categoryForm").submit(function(){
                $.ajax({
                type:'POST', 
                url: 'actions/add-category.php', 
                data: serializedData, 
                beforeSubmit:  function(){
                        return $("#categoryForm").validate();
                    },
                success: function(response) {
                     $('#status').html(response);
                    }
                });
        return false;
       });


});
```

it pass the validation and send the ajax request before validating the form
i tried to make the request if the validation true

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#errors').hide();       
    var serializedData= $("#categoryForm").serialize();
    $("#categoryForm").submit(function(){
        if($("#categoryForm").validate()){
                $.ajax({
                type:'POST', 
                url: 'actions/add-category.php', 
                data: serializedData, 
                success: function(response) {
                     $('#status').html(response);
                    }
                });
        }
        return false;
       });


});
```

but this not working too

Comment: `alert($("#categoryForm").validate())` what's returns?

Answer (score 0):

Dont submit the form in any case, do the check when the submit button is clicked - and then if it succedeed - do the submiting.
Try to do it as follows:

```
$("#submitButton").click(function(){
          if($("#categoryForm").validate()){
                  $.ajax({
                  type:'POST',
                   url: 'actions/add-category.php',
                   data: serializedData,
                   success: function(response) {
                       $('#status').html(response);
                       //if true: 
                       $("#categoryForm").submit();
                          }
                      });


                  }
             return false;
     });
```